# Custom core data properties Swift

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to have an attribute for my `Event` entities that is a string version of it's `date` attribute which is an `Int64`.

My entity's .swift file looks like this:

```
public class Event: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var date: Int64
    let weekDays = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
    let months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
}
```

I've also added a Transient property called `daySectionIdentifier` of type String in my `.xcdatamodeld` editor.

In order to calculate the value for this `daySectionIdentifier` I've added the following code:

```
extension Event {
    public var daySectionIdentifier: String {
        let d = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(self.date))
        let cal = Calendar.current
        let day = cal.component(.day, from: d)
        let month = cal.component(.month, from: d)
        let weekday = weekDays[cal.component(.weekday, from: d) - 1]
        let headerStr = "\(weekday) \(months[month-1]) \(day)"  // format: "Monday, March 2"
        return headerStr
    }
}
```

I'm skeptical if I'm adding this transient property correctly though. I keep seeing examples with `get` and `set` as well as `willAccessValueForKey` online in different examples. Is the way I'm doing this correct or do I need to add other stuff to make this work? Note I'll be using this `daySectionIdentifier` to section out a `UITableView`.

Comment: If you don't need KVC (key-value coding) the way is correct. But why don't you use `DateFormatter` to create the date string?

Comment: hmm I'll look into it. Wasn't aware of such a thing.